# ReactJS: Passing values to child component after API call is finished

Tags: reactjs, input, components, missing-data

In my application I have a module called "Categories" where I have two components (Add & Edit). I have created a Child component called "Form". This Form component acts as a child component to both, Add & Edit, components.

The "Add" component, its working completely fine. However, the "Edit" component, which should be pre-filled with the existing values, is loading with the empty inputs. I am already passing the fetched values to the "Form" component and updating the state in child component on `componentDidMount` method but its not working.

**Here is my code:**
*Edit.jsx*

```
componentWillMount()
{
    Axios
        .get('/api/category/edit/' + this.props.match.params.token)
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.status == false)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                this.setState({
                    token: response.data.token,
                    title: response.data.title,
                    status: response.data.status,
                    description: response.data.description
                });
            }
        });
}

...

render()
{
    ...
    <Form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} edit={this.state} />
    ...
}
```

*Form.jsx*

```
componentDidMount()
{
    this.setState({
        title: this.props.edit.title,
        description: this.props.edit.description,
        status: this.props.edit.status
    });

    console.log(this.props.edit);
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

If I `console.log(this.props.edit)` in the `render` method of the "Form" component then all the values are displayed.

How to fix this issue..?

Comment: i think your componentDidMount() is not triggered when u pass the form data...
try directly pass the edit props to where you want...

Comment: @sathishkumar I tried your solution and the values popped up but now the fields are not editable. Isn't there anyway which triggers after the api call is finished and updates the state of the child component..?

Comment: show your full Form code ?

Comment: A friend of mine suggested me that in the case of "Edit" I should write the API code in the "Form" component and maintain the state. Is it feasible to do so..?

Comment: my suggestion explore the redux-form form reactjs form handling...